# Excel process still running even after .Quit

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The Excel process doesn't stop running after I run my Outlook VBA macro. I suspect it's caused by some Excel Object functions, but I'm really not sure which.
The problem also manifests itself by creating multiple .tmp files in the folder where my Excel Workbook is located.(I think?)
I will post the code that I use to open and close Excel, and all the methods that use an Excel Object.

```
Option Explicit
Public xlApp As Object
Public xlWB As Object
Public xlSheet As Object

Sub LeaveRequests()
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim bXStarted As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
     'Get Excel set up
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 filePath = enviro & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\path.txt"
 Open filePath For Input As #1
 Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strPath
 Loop
 Close #1
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(enviro & strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Process the message record
    On Error Resume Next
    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:NB").entirecolumn.AutoFit
    For j = 2 To 367
        If xlSheet.cells(1, j).Value <> Date And xlSheet.cells(1, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            xlSheet.Columns(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
        If xlSheet.cells(1, j).Value = Date Then
            xlSheet.Columns(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            xlSheet.Columns(j).Select
            If xlSheet.cells(2, j).Value = "Monday" Then
                For i = 2 To j - 1
                xlSheet.Columns(i).Hidden = True
                Next i
            End If
     xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If
End Sub
```

That's the opening and closing of Excel.
I also have a sub that is called during an inbox iteration in the leaverequests sub.

```
Sub FillIn(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As Date, ByVal z As Date, ByVal id As String)
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim date1Pos As Integer
    Dim date2Pos As Integer
    Dim datePos As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
        lastRow = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
        date1Pos = 0
        date2Pos = 0
        For i = 3 To lastRow
            If xlSheet.cells(i, 1).Value = id Then
                currentRow = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
            For j = 2 To 367
                If xlSheet.cells(1, j).Value = y Then
                    date1Pos = j
                End If
                If xlSheet.cells(1, j).Value = z Then
                    date2Pos = j
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If date1Pos <> 0 And date2Pos <> 0 Then
                datePos = date1Pos
                For j = 1 To date2Pos + 1 - date1Pos
                    xlSheet.cells(currentRow, datePos).Value = x
                    xlSheet.cells(currentRow, datePos).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    datePos = datePos + 1
                Next j
            End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `For j = 2 To 367` does not seem to have a matching `Next`

Comment: It does, it's right above `If date1Pos <> 0 and date2Pos <> 0 Then`, I'll try indentating the code.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see the `Next J` in LeaveRequests

Comment: I recommend Smart Indenter  http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp ;-)
(I have nothing to do whith them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your Excel object variables declared on module level and public:

```
Public xlApp As Object
```

This means: they will keep their reference to Excel indefinitely, and thus prevent Excel from closing, unless you explicitly set them to `Nothing`:

```
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

after closing the workbook / Excel.

It is considered better programming practice to use local variables, and pass them as needed to called functions (e.g. from `LeaveRequests()` to `FillIn()`).

E.g.:

```
Sub LeaveRequests()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    ' stuff, loops, ...
    Call FillIn(xlSheet, x, y, z, id)

End Sub

Sub FillIn(xlSheet As Object, ByVal x As String, ByVal y As Date, ByVal z As Date, ByVal id As String)
    ' as is
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! The process gets terminated using those commands. How do you suggest I pass objects as variables in functions tho? I had to declare them public because having them local in `LeaveRequests()` would make it impossible to write using `FillIn()`, and it also made the `For i = 3 to lastRow` behave strangely, as it made the `i` to be a constant 3, and even though it iterated the correct number of times.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the below code, This is an overkill but it worked for me, I had used this as an function, but this code can be used as On Error GoTo or Sub rou

```
Dim objWMIService
Dim colProcessList
Dim objProcess
Dim strComputer

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")  ' Task mgr
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name in ('EXCEL.EXE') ")  '''''','Chrome.exe','iexplore.exe'

For Each objProcess in colProcessList 
    objProcess.Terminate() 
Next
```

Comment: Where exactly do you suggest I add this code? After the xlWB.Close ?

Comment: You can use the above code instead of `xlApp.Quit` . For e.g you can create a function and write this code and then call that function instead of `xlApp.Quit`

Comment: I get a syntax error on `objProcess.Terminate()`, I removed the brackets, but the end result is still the same, the process doesn't terminate.